# Problems with redirecting url in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, this is my first time hosting a node js application in windows. I have been able to successfully host the node application and get my server file up and running. But then I want to know how to navigate to other get/post requests after hosting it. When I was doing it in in my IDE, everything was working perfectly. But now, when I tried to navigate to other get requests, I keep getting served the same server log. This is how my server file looks like. -

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var Flutterwave = require("flutterwave");
var flutterwave = new Flutterwave("******","*******");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello, world! [helloworld sample; iisnode version is ' + process.env.IISNODE_VERSION + ', node version is ' + process.version + ']');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);

/*
app.listen(3001, function (req,res) {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
*/

app.get("/",function (req,res) {
  res.render("index",{'title':'helloworld'});
});

app.post('/pay', function (req, res) {
    var jsonString = '';
    var validateoption = req.body.validateoption;
    var authmodel = req.body.authmodel;
    var cardno = req.body.cardno;
    var cvv = req.body.cvv;
    var expirymonth = req.body.expirymonth;
    var expiryyear = req.body.expiryyear;

    console.log("Validateoption",req.body.validateoption);

    flutterwave.Card.tokenize({
        "validateoption":validateoption,
        "authmodel":authmodel, /*Only NOAUTH and BVN are accepted*/
        "bvn": "(Optional:Only needed where authmodel is BVN)",
        "cardno":cardno,
        "cvv":cvv,
        "expirymonth":expirymonth,
        "expiryyear":expiryyear

    }, function(err,resp,body) {
        console.log(resp.body.data);
        res.json(resp.body.data);
    });
});
```

we.config file on IIS node-

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>



    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

1. localhost/node/Fluterwave/server.js/pay
2. localhost/node/Fluterwave/server.js/
```

--- They give the same message `Hello, world! [helloworld sample; iisnode version is 0.2.21, node version is v6.9.2]`